# Bootstrap proper image stacking

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I designed this one as a self learning project but having two problems now.

http://shahsaad.base.pk/

First are the three photos under the submit button. I want them to display in that blue background container only, so I made three columns of length 4 (col-md-4) in a row. They display well in medium and large devices but the problem is when the page is viewed in small devices or extra small devices, they all go wrong. They go out of that blue container div, even when I tried to set the minimum height of that blue container to the size of the screen using jQuery, so that the blue container height automatically increases with the content, but its not increasing. Then I tried to counter this making all columns col-xs-4 like this:

http://shahsaad.base.pk/index2.html

but when viewed on tablets or mobile devices they appear too small.

The second problem is that when I add these three images in a row, a small white gap appears on all of the right side of the page, underneath the navigation bar.

I have been trying to resolve this for an hour now but still can't figure out how to do it properly. Please help.

Here is my code:

CSS

```
<style>

    .navbar-brand {

        font-size:1.7em;

    }

    #topContainer {
        background-image:url("background.jpg");
        height:800px;
        width:100%;
        background-size:cover;

    }
    #topRow{
        margin-top:100px;
        text-align:center;

        color:black;

    }
    #topRow h1{
        font-size:300%;



    }
    .roundDiv{
        border-radius:10px;
        background-color: #ffffff;  
        opacity:0.5;
        color:black;
    }
    .marginTop{
        margin-top:30px;
    }
    .centerDiv{
        text-align:center;

    }
    .title {
        margin-top:100px;
        text-size:300%
    }
    a:hover {
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    .col-md-4{
        text-align:justify;
    }
    #footer {
        background-color:#000000;
        height:40px;
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
        color:#3777A0;
    }


</style>
```

body

```
<body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar-header">

                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Soon Valley</a>

            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                    <li><a href="#index.html" class="active">Home</a><li>
                    <li><a href="">Photos</a><li>
                    <li><a href="">Videos</a><li>
                    <li><a href="">Notes</a><li>

                </ul>

                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>

                <form>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="container contentContainer" id="topContainer">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="topRow">

                <h1 class="marginTop"><b>Soon Valley</b></h1>

                <p class="lead">One of the most beautiful valleys of Pakistan</p>

                <h3 class="marginTop"><b>Interested? Join our mailing list.</b></h3>

                <form class="marginTop">

                    <div class="input-group">

                        <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email address"/>

                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg marginTop" />

                </form>



            </div>


            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-4 text-center marginTop">

                    <img src="pic.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle"/>

                </div> 

                <div class="col-md-4 text-center marginTop">

                <img src="daip.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle"/>

                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 text-center marginTop">

                    <img src="jahlar.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle"/>

                </div>

            </div>


        </div>



    </div>

    <div class="container contentContainer">

        <!--

        <div class="row" class="centerDiv">

            <h1 class="centerDiv title"><b>Our Photo Gallery</b></h1>

        </div>

        !-->

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <a href="">
                <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span> Photo Gallery</h2>
                </a>
                <p>A brief Description of the photo Gallery, And some more details just to fill this space
                you know.A brief Description of the photo Gallery, And some more details just to fill this space
                you know.</p>


            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <a href="">
                <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video"></span> Videos</h2>
                </a>
                <p>A brief Description of the photo Gallery, And some more details just to fill this space
                you know.A brief Description of the photo Gallery, And some more details just to fill this space
                you know.</p>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <a href="">
                <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> Notes</h2>
                </a>
                <p>A brief Description of the photo Gallery, And some more details just to fill this space
                you know.A brief Description of the photo Gallery, And some more details just to fill this space
                you know.</p>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="container" id="footer">

        </p>Designed by: <a href="http://www.facebook.com/shahsaad"><b>Shah Saad Hamadani</b></a>

    </div>



<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(".contentContainer").css("min-height",$(window).height()); 

</script>
```

Comment: You have many open and or not closed HTML tags. Open up your page in firefox and look for the red tags.

Comment: just doubled checked all the tags. One of the form was not closed properly so did that but that didn't help either. Am I doing something wrong in the javascript?